# Matthews Correlation Coefficient yielding values outside of [-1,1]

Tags: correlation, c#

I'm using the formula found on Wikipedia for calculating Matthew's Correlation Coefficient.  It works fairly well, most of the time, but I'm running into problems in my tool's implementation, and I'm not seeing the problem.

MCC = ((TP*TN)-(FP*FN))/sqrt(((TP + FP)( TP + FN )( TN + FP )( TN + FN )))

Where TP, TN, FP, and FN are the non-negative, integer counts of the appropriate fields.
Which should only return values $\epsilon$ [-1,1]
My implementation is as follows:

```
double ret;
if ((TruePositives + FalsePositives) == 0 || (TruePositives + FalseNegatives) == 0 ||
   ( TrueNegatives + FalsePositives) == 0 || (TrueNegatives + FalseNegatives) == 0)
//To avoid dividing by zero
    ret = (double)(TruePositives * TrueNegatives - 
                     FalsePositives * FalseNegatives);

else{
    double num = (double)(TruePositives * TrueNegatives - 
                           FalsePositives * FalseNegatives);

    double denom = (TruePositives + FalsePositives) * 
                   (TruePositives + FalseNegatives) * 
                   (TrueNegatives + FalsePositives) * 
                   (TrueNegatives + FalseNegatives);
    denom = Math.Sqrt(denom);
    ret = num / denom;
                }
return ret;
```

When I use this, as I said it works properly most of the time, but for instance if TP=280, TN = 273, FP = 67, and FN = 20, then we get:
MCC =  (280*273)-(67*20)/sqrt((347*300*340*293)) = 75100/42196.06= (approx) 1.78
Is this normal behavior of Matthews Correlation Coefficient?  I'm a programmer by trade, so statistics aren't a part of my formal training.  Also, I've looked at questions with answers, and none of them discuss this behavior.  Is it a bug in my code or in the formula itself?

Comment: I wonder if you are getting values outside $[-1,1]$ when your first conditional returns true?

Comment: No, I've looked into this- the way the formula works (since no field can be negative), for one of the pairs (TP+FP, for instance) in the bottom to be 0, (TP+FP = 0 iff FP= TP = 0) the numerator necessarily needs to be zero because each of those terms appears once on both sides of the - sign in the numerator; therefore, if the denominator is zero, then the numerator has a zero on both sides of the subtraction, so it simply returns zero.

Comment: Are TP, FP, TN, and FN *counts*? Or are they proportions?

Comment: They are counts. I'll edit the above to make it clear.

Comment: Where does the $42196.06$ come from? Obviously the square root must be close to $300^2\approx 100K$.  (It's actually $105,723.1$.)

Comment: I agree with whuber: I get 0.738 for your numbers using that formula, not 1.78.

Comment: If the code itself is producing values beyond the range $[-1,1]$, then it must be supplied with negative inputs. To track this down, include validity checks of the input.

Comment: @Alexis One of the pairs must be equal to zero.  If (TP + FN) = 0, then (TP x TN) - (FP x FN) = 0, because TP and FN are both equal to zero, since they can't be negative.

Comment: @Whuber Good catch.  I'm not sure how I missed that!  Thanks, let me try duplicating the error in excel this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is clear and looks correct.  (But one's eyes can always deceive.)

One issue is a concern whether the output is guaranteed to lie between -1 and 1.  Assuming all inputs are nonnegative, though, we can round the numerator *up* and the denominator *down*, thereby overestimating the result, by zeroing out all the "False*" terms, producing

```
TP*TN / Sqrt(TP*TN*TP*TN) = 1.
```

The lower limit is obtained similarly by zeroing out all the "True*" terms.  Therefore, **working code cannot produce a value larger than 1 in size unless it is presented with invalid input.**

I therefore recommend placing a guard (such as an `Assert` statement) to assure the inputs are nonnegative.  (Clearly it matters not in the preceding argument whether they are integral.)  Place another assertion to check that the output is in the interval [-1,1].  Together, these will detect either or both of (a) invalid inputs or (b) an error in the calculation.

Comment: As a sanity check, I typed in the multiplication manually; 347∗300∗340∗293 and set that to a variable.  Immediately got a compiler error - that expression overflows!  Which I wasn't being alerted to at runtime.

Comment: Ah, of course! You need to be casting these terms into doubles before performing the arithmetic.  Your use of typecasting in the code should have alerted us to the fact that the variables were declared to be some kind of integers.